# Angular Material Table Filter has Extra Line

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material

I'm building an Angular Material table using `<mat-table>` and would like to apply a filter. The filter works, but there is an extra filter line being rendered. Has anyone seen this issue before / have an idea for how to fix it? I'm thinking it might be an import issue but haven't been able to pinpoint it.

[image]

The extra line is a `<mat-input-underline mat-form-field-underline>` element.

Here are the relevant code snippits:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="field">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Header</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.field}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

export interface Field {
    field: String;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-single-col-list',
    templateUrl: './single-col-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./single-col-list.component.scss']
})
export class SingleColListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() colData: Field[];
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['field'];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.colData);
    }

    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

**Imports**

```
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
BrowserModule,
CalendarModule,
CdkTableModule,
ChartModule,
DataViewModule,
DropdownModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatButtonToggleModule,
MatCardModule,
MatExpansionModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatGridListModule,
MatIconModule,
MatInputModule,
MatListModule,
MatMenuModule,
MatPaginatorModule,
MatProgressBarModule,
MatProgressSpinnerModule,
MatRadioModule,
MatSlideToggleModule,
MatSortModule,
MatTableModule,
MatTabsModule,
MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
NguCarouselModule,
PanelModule
```

Comment: did you include any css?

Comment: None that would affect this behavior

Comment: Just hide line with css

Comment: @Antoniossss that would work but isn't really getting to the root of the problem

Comment: may be because of lot of mat imports. Only import the modules that you need for the table.

Comment: Ah you mean there are 2 underlines?

Comment: Can you create reproducable stackblitz ?

Comment: Never faced that problem before

Comment: Also header is very missleading as it has nothing to do with MatDataTable besides beeing in the same template markup as troublesome input...

Comment: Could it be because of `MDBBootstrapModule`? Could you attach a screenshot of the DevTools?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, I was able to simply remove the `<mat-form-field>` element and just go with the straight `<input ..>` element and it worked:

```
<input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="field">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Header</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.field}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

However, not quite sure how to reconcile this behavior with this example: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview